# Extract a particular record from MongoDB where the records use Object GUID in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

One of the Mongo objects I use (referred to as 'Admin' here) uses GUID as the primary key and has a list of 'DailyActivities' which contains datevalue and another list called 'Subactivities'. The Admin object looks like something below. I am struggling to find resources in C# that will help extract DailyActivities that only corresponds to a particular date with Subactivities that has a category of 'Power Consumption'.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2b7b887df7ce464404dc7d"),
    "DailyActivities" : [ 
        {
            "datetime" : ISODate("2017-12-09T16:29:00.916Z"),
            "Subactivities" : [ 
                {
                    "entryDate" : ISODate("2017-12-09T06:30:26.658Z"),
                    "category" : "Power Consumption"
                }, 
                {
                    "entryDate" : ISODate("2017-12-09T06:30:26.658Z"),
                    "category" : "Machinery"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "datetime" : ISODate("2017-12-13T00:00:00.916Z"),
            "Subactivities" : [ 
                {
                    "entryDate" : ISODate("2017-12-13T06:30:26.658Z"),
                    "category" : "Lamination"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The result I would like to receive should be:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c7044f07ef75175b2b8efd6"),
    "entryDate" : ISODate("2017-12-09T06:30:26.658Z"),
    "category" : "Power Consumption"
}
```

Comment: What does your desired output document look like?

Comment: @dnickless Just need the subactivity object as follows without the parent. So, just plain ---  

{
      "entryDate" : ISODate("2017-12-09T06:30:26.658Z"),
     "category" : "Power Consumption",
}

Answer (score 0):

Right now, I don't have the time to complete this exercise but here is something to get you going. I shall edit and improve this (as in convert it into some c# a lot of which won't be possible using a typed approach...) next week.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        "DailyActivities": {
            $filter: {
                input: "$DailyActivities",
                cond: {
                    $eq: [ "$$this.datetime", ISODate("2017-12-09T16:29:00.916Z") ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$DailyActivities"
}, {
    $unwind: "$DailyActivities.Subactivities"
}, {
    $replaceRoot: {
        "newRoot": "$DailyActivities.Subactivities"
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "category": "Power Consumption"
    }
}])
```

Comment: The above was really useful and I could convert to C# code, many thanks @dnickless

Answer (score 0):

let me offer you a solution which uses MongoDAL as the data access layer. it's a wrapper around the c# driver so you get all the features of the driver plus a highly typed api.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using MongoDAL;

namespace AdminActs
{
    class Admin : Entity
    {
        public DailyActivity[] DailyActivities { get; set; }
    }

    class DailyActivity
    {
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public SubActivity[] SubActivities { get; set; }
    }

    class SubActivity
    {
        public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("activities");

            var now = DateTime.Now;

            var admin = new Admin
            {
                DailyActivities = new DailyActivity[]
                {
                    new DailyActivity{
                        Time = now,
                        SubActivities = new SubActivity[]
                        {
                            new SubActivity{
                                Category ="Power Consumption",
                                EntryDate = DateTime.Now}
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            admin.Save();

            var subActivities = admin.Collection()
                                     .SelectMany(a => a.DailyActivities)
                                     .Where(da => da.Time == now)
                                     .SelectMany(da => da.SubActivities)
                                     .Where(sa => sa.Category == "Power Consumption");

            var res = subActivities.ToArray();

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```